# string manipulation in AWK or in C

Tags: c, string, text, awk

I have a problem, I have a file with some number delimited by "". For example "125" etc.

An example of the file is:

```
10.0.0.0 11.0.0.0 "1200"
10.0.0.1 11.0.0.0.1 "200"
11.0.0.1 11.0.0.2 "320"
```

I use `AWK` for take the data but my problem is that I have to take only the integer value of the third column without "" because after I need to have some calculation with this numbers.
The solution is good also in `C` language.
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: _"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."_

Comment: _a file with some number_ is not an adequate description of your data. Please show us a representative sample of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, you'll have to strip off the quotes manually

```
$ echo '"2134"' | awk '{gsub(/(^")|("$)/,"",$1); print $1+2}'
2136
```

Obviously, this is not a C answer.

Comment: Actually, it is sufficient to remove only the first quote: awk will treat the value `123abc` as the number 123 in a numeric context.